# how to fix Enable compression for t.dtscout.com/…i google insights

Tags: wordpress, compression

I'm try to optimize my site & get a good score in Google insights Test

But Now it's showing this

```
Enable compression for the following resources to reduce their transfer size by 1.1KiB (55% reduction).
Compressing http://t.dtscout.com/…i/?l=http%3A%2F%2Fkatmoviehd.co.in%2F&j= could save 1.1KiB (55% reduction).
Hide details
```

Test Site - KatmovieHD.co.in/

Gzip compression is already enabled and I don't know how to Fix this Issue ..

[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcuQ4.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove Histats counter from your website and then the problem will be solved. Histats uses a very aggressive tracking system that can cause your page sometimes to load forever although your website has already loaded. Not to mention other downsides like some antiviruses that can block access to your website. I highly recommend Google Analytics as they do provide same features and even more.

Comment: Google analytics is good however i find that fact that they dont have the widgets to show the users the traffic websites gets is a downside, histats is good for show that users we get this many traffic ..etc

Comment: Today I just notice this domain after enable `Content-Security-Policy` on my server , this is snake behavior from Histats to inject this type of Advertisement code , now that code didn't load since I blocked from the server `add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' *.some.com  www.google-analytics.com *.histats.com data: blob: 'unsafe-inline' ;" always;`